# How to change artboard size in AI CS6?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize

Sorry can't find this simple feature. I was asked for document size at creation time but don't know how to change this later.

Comment: In case it helps anyone else, I came here looking for option to resize artboard manually by dragging edges, figured out solution was `File > Document Setup > Edit Artboards` and then you can resize the artboard manually.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Select the Artboard Tool on the Tool bar (..or use the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>).

[image: artboard]

You can then click an artboard and change its size with the options in the Control bar across the top of the screen.

Another method is to highlight the artboard in the Artboard Panel (Window > Artboards) and choose Artboard Options from the Panel menu.

[image: artboard options]

Comment: Another way you can do this is just by double-clicking on the artboard you'd like to edit in the Artboard Panel.

Comment: And just in case you haven't found it yet, shift+O is the default keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 4):

Click on Window then select artboards

[image]

Then in that window click on the symbol to the right your artboard. This will bring up Artboard Options. There you can modify the width or height.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

There's a Document Setup Button on top Toolbar. Click it and click Edit ArtBoard.

Source - 
http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Canvas-Size-in-Adobe-Illustrator